# How to connect an android tablet with a laptop using a USB cable?

Tags: usb

My [AAkash 2](http://www.ubislate.com/) tablet has a mini-USB port and comes with a cable to convert the mini port to standard USB female port for connecting flash drives etc.

I want to connect the tablet to a laptop using this port. For this I bought the standard male-male USB cable, which attaches to the female port of the USB connector of the tablet and female port of the laptop.

But no devices are found by either the laptop or the tablet. Do I need to make any setting changes to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need to install appropriate USB drivers on your PC in order to have the tablet recognized by Windows (assuming your laptop has Windows OS installed.)

Datawind's [site](http://ubislate.com/ubislate/index.html) doesn't seem to have any drivers available for download, so your best bet would be to [contact them](http://ubislate.com/contact/index.html) directly, or try your luck with a [Google search](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Aakash+2%22+usb+drivers&oq=%22Aakash+2%22+usb+drivers) (be mindful of viruses posing as drivers).

Comment: Good-buy to the old times of special drivers, a while already now there's the [Universal USB driver](http://adbdriver.com/) available which should work with most devices. All Hail to Kosh, once more :)

Comment: @Izzy: I tried the Universal USB Driver, but it wasnt able to detect the android tablet that I had connected, any more ideas.

Comment: No other then as Chahk already mentioned: contact the manufacturer/seller.